# App Component Not Called When Routing from Login Page to Dashboard

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a login Component on Successful authentication

in login.component.ts 

`login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }`

I save UserObject in LocalStorage and then

i redirect to Dashboard Page using

`this.router.navigate`

In My App.component.ts i check if UserObject is in LocalStorage

`constructor(private router: Router) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
      this.userLoggedIn = true;
      const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
      this.userObject = user['return_object'];
    }
}`

I use userLoggedIn variable in app.component.html to conditionally show header and left navigation but for some reason the code in App.component.ts doesnt executes can someone point me to the right direction.

Comment: your login component is different?

Comment: i dont see any routing code ,, can you please provide full code

Comment: can you write same code in your `ngOnInit()`, by implementing `implements OnInit ` let me know if there is still issue

Comment: @PranayRana Same code in ngOnInit also doesnt works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you please write you code like this,

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(event:Event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
         //you code for checking and navigation
    }
  });
}
```

suggestion is to subscribe route event and do action based on it , because constructor get executed once only when component get created till get destroyed.

Comment: should i put this code in App.component.ts I guess the control does not comes in this file again.